# Как вставить переменную в Sql-запрос?

Tags: c#, sql

Как в это запрос вместо 74 вставить переменную ?

```
SqlCommand SelectDannieComand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ParserDB] WHERE Id > 74", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: Вот тут пример работы посмотрите https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx  все что касается параметра `@ID`

Comment: [Следует ли включать метки в заголовок вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3480/213987)

Comment: @AK, спасибо, не знал - думал делал только лучше для индексации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-грамотному это делается через параметризованные запросы:

```
private void SomeThing(string id)
{
    string sqlExpression = "SELECT Abc, Def FROM [ParserDB] WHERE Id > @id";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@id", id);

            command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Есть и более простой вариант (через форматирование строки), он проще, но небезопасный (есть возможность SQL-инъекций), поэтому не рекомендуется к использованию.

Также вариант с плейсхолдерами даёт возможность SQL-серверу кешировать планы выполнения запросов, см. например [тут](http://www.queryprocessor.ru/fast-in-ssms-slow-in-app-part3/).

Comment: AK, как всегда спасибо ! Только что разбирался с параметрами, собрал тоже самое, но не мог проверить, теперь понимаю что всё правильно собрал.

Answer (score 3):

Вам стоит передавать данные через параметры `SqlCommand.Parameters`. Или вообще отказаться от ручной работы с `SqlCommand`/`SqlDataReader`

В качестве в качестве альтернативы `SqlCommand` стоит посмотреть любой легковесный ORM, например, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper):

Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Dapper
```

---

```
using Dapper;

public class Dannie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeColumn { get; set; }
}

...
private void GetDannie(int id)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var d = connection.Query<Dannie>(
            "SELECT * FROM [ParserDB] WHERE Id > @id", new { id })
            .ToList();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Плюс за Dapper. Легковесно, современно, удобно.